# Are these representations of the Bellman Equation equivalent?

Tags: machine-learning, dynamic-programming, markov-chains

I've found two slightly different Bellman Equations. Are they totally equivalent?

I see the one on the bottom has an **s'** in the reward. Does this or anything else about the groupings change anything fundamental about the equation?

I'm not totally math literate so I'm not sure which **max a** we are taking. Is it just the action in the summation for both equations? '**max**' means to go with the a that yields the largest number, so does that mean the **a** in the **R** and the **T** can both be whichever yields the maximum?

How about for the summation s'? Are we just adding up the **s'** in the **T(s,a,s')** part of each equation?

$$V(s) = \underset a \max \left( R(s,a) + \gamma \sum_{s'} {T(s,a,s')V(s')}\right)$$

$$V(s) = \underset a \max \sum_{s'} {T(s,a,s')}\left[ R(s,a,s') + \gamma V(s')\right]$$